# Rails Devise Send confirmation email after Facebook signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth, mailer

**Problem:** How do I send the user an email after they sign up for the first time with Facebook? I'm using device and omniauth.

I have confirmation emails working for regular signup with devise. I need to send an email when the user gets added to my database for the first time after signing in with Facebook. **Where in the code is this happening?**

I tried adding a line of code sending the email in my omniauth_callbacks_controller.

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

# omniauth_callbacks_controller

def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    facebook = "www.facebook.com"

    if @user.persisted?
        print "User persisted"
        sign_in @user, :event => :authentication
        set_flash_message(:notice,:success,:kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?

        # I SENT THE EMAIL HERE

    else
        session["device.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

However, this just sends the user a confirmation email EVERY time they log in with Facebook, which is not what I want. I want to simply send the email the first time they log in.

The email should be sent in the registrations_controller. However, when users are signing up with Facebook, this controller is never used.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def create
build_resource(sign_up_params)
if resource.save
  if resource.active_for_authentication?
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
    sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    # Tell the UserMailer to send a welcome email after save
    UserMailer.welcome_email(current_user).deliver_later
    return render :json => {:success => true}
  else
    set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
    expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
    return render :json => {:success => true}
  end
else
  clean_up_passwords resource
  invalid_signin_attempt
end
end
```

Would like to know the right way to send a confirmation to the user after signing up with Facebook.

Comment: can you post your model for the devise Model. Usually if you use :confirmable in the model devise will send an email. Check devise Docs for details. You also need to adjust the migrations for the model to store the tokens.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to confirm users signing with Facebook?

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

It looks like your `User.from_omniauth` function behaves like a `find_or_create` call. That means that the controller has no knowledge of whether the user was just created or is being fetched from an existing identity in the database.

If the user is created as part of this `from_omniauth` call, then you should be able to just rely on the Devise `:confirmable` module. Otherwise, the user is created before you get back the OAuth credentials, so you need to handle it manually.

The code in the `from_omniauth` function likely looks something like this:

```
def self.from_omniauth(token)
  user = User.find(token: token)
  if user.nil?
    user = User.create(token: token, ...)
    # ...
  end
  # ...
end
```

There might be an intermediary `Token`, `Identity`, or other such class, but the logic should be the same.

### Fix

There are two easy ways to fix this:

1. Include a `created` boolean as part of the `from_omniauth` return value, which the controller can then use to gate the confirmation email on.
2. Move the "create" part of the "find or create" logic out into the controller, so that the email can be sent as part of the "create" path.

### Aside

Also, I'd suggest using the Devise `resource.send_confirmation_instructions` function and piggybacking your email off that. That way, all welcome emails share the same code and you're not maintaining a separate module just for Facebook/OAuth login.